# .htaccess: script 'index\\.php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: .htaccess

I'm getting lots of errors in my log for this:

> script '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/index\\.php' not found or unable to stat

(Yes, 2 x '\')

There is an index.php file in the root, and I've tried many .htaccess methods to get rid of index\.php, but either it causes problems (as some index.php links are valid) or just refuses to work.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

I do use mod_rewrite to redirect like so:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/? index\.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
```

is the index.php in the redirect causing the error?

How can I use .htaccess to redirect calls to index\\.php to the homepage?

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to redirect, browse to, or include index\.php at all?  Why not just index.php?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/? index.php?search=$1 [NC,L]